# Action when sidebars updated

Tags: actions, sidebar

Is there any action that triggers after the sidebars have been updated? For example, for menus, I use `wp_update_nav_menu`, but I didn't find any way to do something alike with sidebars.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is what you need: `sidebar_admin_setup`

More info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/sidebar_admin_setup

Comment: Well, this actually doesn't trigger when any sidebar is modified, but when the admin sidebar page is setup (more specifically when globals $wp_registered_widgets and $wp_registered_widget_controls are defined). Unfortunately this is not what I need. I need something that triggers everytime a widget is added or removed from a sidebar.

Answer (score -1):

*@Mateus Felipe*, there are a couple of ways to handle this with hooks, [`wp_ajax_save-widget`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_ajax_save_widget/), [`wp_ajax_widgets-order`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-admin/js/widgets.js#L391), [`customize_save_{$id_base}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_save_id_base/), [`wp_ajax_customize_save`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_save/), or [`customize_save_response`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_save_response/) or [`delete_widget`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/delete_widget/) when just in delete event.

**Example**

```
foreach ( array( 'wp_ajax_save-widget', 'wp_ajax_widgets-order', 'wp_ajax_customize_save' ) as $action ) {
    add_action( $action, function() {
        //do something, i.e add post meta for post with ID 1
        add_post_meta ( 1, 'fruit', 'banana', true );
    }, 1 ); //must use priority, example 1
}
```

Also, you can hook `update_option` with option `sidebars_widgets` in set event see `wp_set_sidebars_widgets`. Please to consider when JS browser disabled. I hope this helps.

Comment: partial and partially wrong answer :(. ajax from the customizer is not a save and should not be treated like it is, and the customizer save is unlikely to contain actual required sidebar id. hooking on the option change is probably the only somewhat valid way, but the answer lacks any explanation on how to use it for what the OP wants :(

Comment: @Mark Kaplun of course :). lets the op achieve it with the condition such as base on widget id, etc, and I think he know how to use hooking on the option, I hope. :)

Comment: for the specific OP, we can hope, but in general the structure of that option is probably very mysterious to 96% of WP developers, therefor IMHO it is essential part of the answer  if you want it to be useful to mediocre programmers as well as the elite ones :)

Comment: Well, in documentation it says `wp_ajax_save-widget` and `wp_ajax_widgets-order` are functions, not hooks, so how could I know it? About `wp_ajax_customize_save`, `customize_save_{$id_base}` and `customize_save_response`, could you please hint me how to use them in my specific case? About `delete_widget`, it's really useful, but it handles deleting, and not updating. About `update_option`, maybe it's the better solution for me, I'm going to try it.

Comment: Reading about `update_option`, it seems it triggers **before** the option updated, so I looked at the source of `wp-includes/option.php` and I found that the best options for me (at least by now) is to use `update_option_{$option}` or `updated_option`.

Comment: Sadly, `update_option_sidebars_widgets` doesn't seem to work. At least it doesn't print anything that I try with `echo`, `print_r` or `var_dump`.